# Create-react-app build files tilde ~ character

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, create-react-app

Is there a way to not use the tilde character in the create-react-app build js file names?

After I run `npm run build` on my create-react-app, I get a couple `runtime~main.[hash].js` files in the /static/js/ folder . My destination file system does not allow tilde characters in file or folder names.

Can I change config somewhere to output `runtime-main.[hash].js` with a `-` instead of tilde??

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/production-build

Comment: I found `new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/])` in `\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js` - I believe this is where the name is generated. Can I just change this? I believe I need to eject first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved without ejecting:

-Install rescripts: `npm install @rescripts/cli --save-dev` in your project

-Create a file .rescriptsrc.js at the root directory of your project and put the code below inside:

```
module.exports = config => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks.automaticNameDelimiter = '_';
    if (config.optimization.runtimeChunk) {
        config.optimization.runtimeChunk = {
            name: entrypoint => `runtime_${entrypoint.name}`
        };
    }
    return config;
};
```

In package.json in sripts section add a new entry `"build-re": "rescripts build"`

Now when running npm run build-re it will generate _ instead of ~ in file names.

https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts

Comment: When I run the `build-r` I'm getting `'rescripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: Because I just ran into this again...  The command to run it is `npm run-script build-re`